# Get Jquery and PHP response from second to second

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page in PHP that does a query in the database at the end of the processing I show the amount of updated records. This process takes a while, in my Jquery I just show the total of affected records, how could I change my Jquery to show from time to time, in case every 1 second it shows the user the amount of records.

```
var form_data = new FormData();

         form_data.append('id', idSel);
         $.ajax({
             url: 'post.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: form_data,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             beforeSend: function () {
                $('.resp').html("<img src='images/spin.gif' alt='Notificação' height='70' width='70'/> ");
            },
             success: function(response) {
```

**ATTENTION** I can not keep calling the PHP page several times, I need to call once and listen to it or receive data from it!

Is it possible for teachers?

Comment: You can't do this with ajax. You could do this with websockets.

Comment: As @Jerodev said, you need websockets. Look into SocketIO or Pusher.

Comment: I would have an easy example calling a php page and within a php page loop I reply with echo ($ cont);